# How to open flutter app webcontainer url from link in email

Tags: flutter, applinks

I'm building webcontainer app and want to open a specific url from my website (staging_mywebsite.com/forgot_pasword) in my flutter app when I click on and link in email that is spesified as (mywebsite.page)

I have setup my andriodManifest for app links and deep links.
I can open my app when clicked on the link in browser, but I want to redirect it directly to staging_mywebsite.com/forgot_pasword in my app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6zyC.png)

I also setup my app links
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PIYb.png)